# How to properly validate collection / list / array in Angular 2?

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

**I want to validate if `myObject.total` is equal to the sum of values of all `myObject.subObjects`**

*This is my **Model***

```
export interface MyObject {
  // some unimportant fields first, then:
  subObjects: MySubObject[],
  total: number,
}

export interface MySubObject {
  value: number;
}
```

*This is my **Form***

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  // simple validation rules for unimportant fields, then:
  myGroup: new FormGroup({
    total: new FormControl({value: ''}),
    subObjects: new FormControl(this.myObject.subObjects)
  }, CustomValidators.myCustomValidator)
```

I have made custom validator `myCustomValidator(group: FormGroup)`, which takes the form group, extracts the necessary values like this `+group.controls['total'].value` and does the necessary validation, but I have hard times with registering it for the list. It works fine whenever I modify the input bound with `total`, but it does not trigger when I add/remove my `subObjects`

*This is my **HTML** (important bits)*

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myObject.total" name="total" [formControl]="form.controls.myGroup.controls.total">

<input [(ngModel)]="myObject.subObjects" name="subObjects" [formControl]="form.controls.myGroup.controls.subObjects" type="hidden">

// here is mechanism for viewing / adding / removing subObjects, bound to [(ngModel)], but not bound to form
```

I do not like this binding whole list to one hidden input, I feel it is wrong, but I do not know how to do it properly.